# IKVM with UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: ikvm

I get the following error when trying to run my simple java class with ikvm on Windows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: dummy (52
.0)
        at IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Unknown Source)

...

        at IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Class.forName0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:361)
```

Since I am able to run the same class on my Mac with mono - it shouldn't be a the JDK version (which is 1.8). I have checked the classpath, which directs to the /lib directory of ikvm and the current directory.

Both ikvm and ikvmc won't work on Windows Server 2012. Everything is accessible - javac, csc, ikvmc. I get the classpath just fine with echo %CLASSPATH%.

I am missing something here - but what? I have been searching and reading through the mailing list; it's apparently the most asked question to be mentioned in the FAQ, but I don't see the next steps of troubleshooting this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I ran into this today.

Comment: Yes, but that was two years ago...

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks anyway.